# DataTables Dynamic displayStart

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I'm trying to get my javascript to use a dynamic value for "displayStart".  I'm getting the data from a php script that returns JSON.
Here is my js:

```
    balance.list = function () {
    $('#balance').dataTable({
        processing: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'php/list.php',
            dataSrc: 'data'
        },
        dom: '<"top"flp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
        pageLength: 50,
        autoWidth: false,
        displayStart: '100',

        columns: [
        {
            width: "10%",
            data: "date"
        }, {
            width: "5%",
            data: "checknum"
        }, {
            width: "75%",
            data: "description"
        }, {
            width: "5%",
            data: "debit"
        }, {
            width: "5%",
            data: "credit"
        }, {
            width: "5%",
            data: "balance"
        }]
    });
};
```

instead of 
    displayStart: '100',
I want it be something like:
    displayStart: displayStart.displayStart,

But I'm setting the dataSrc to data, which is another branch of the JSON

And here is the JSON data:

```
{
  "displayStart":"100",
  "data": [
  {
    "date":"2015-03-27",
    "checknum":null,
    "description":null,
    "debit":"50.00",
    "credit":"0.00",
    "balance":"500.00"
  },
  {
    "date":"2015-03-28",
    "checknum":null,
    "description":null,
    "debit":"0.00",
    "credit":"250.00",
    "balance":"750.00"
  }
  ]
}
```

I've messed around with the ajax portion using a success/error function, but then it doesn't continue on to finish the table.

How do I set the value?

Comment: is this what you want {
  `"displayStart":{"displayStart":"100",},`
  "data": [
  {
    "date":"2015-03-27",
    "checknum":null,
    "description":null,
    "debit":"50.00",
    "credit":"0.00",
    "balance":"500.00"
  },
  {
    "date":"2015-03-28",
    "checknum":null,
    "description":null,
    "debit":"0.00",
    "credit":"250.00",
    "balance":"750.00"
  }
  ]
}

Comment: what is the meaning of displayStart.displayStart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the page after the data has been loaded by adding two event handlers after you DataTables initialization code as shown below.

```
// Handles DataTables AJAX request completion event
$('#balance').on('xhr.dt', function( e, settings, json){
   $(this).data('is-loaded', true);
});

// Handles DataTables table draw event
$('#balance').on('draw.dt', function (){
   if($(this).data('is-loaded')){
      $(this).data('is-loaded', false);
      var api = $(this).DataTable();
      var json = api.ajax.json();
      var page_start = json['displayStart'];

      // Calculate page number
      var page = Math.min(Math.max(0, Math.round(page_start / api.page.len())), api.page.info().pages);

      // Set page
      api.page(page).draw(false);
   }
});
```